# Multithreaded merge sort, adding additional threads

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, sorting

I am facing one problem in multithreaded merge sort algorithm in java.

I should modify the code into 3,4,5,6,7,8 threaded merge sorting by dividing original array into `subArray`s. Currently it has 2 `subArray`s. 
How can I split original array into 3, 4 ,5,6,7,8 `subArray`s to achive my goal?
Moreover, I should write some more methods because `mergeSort` method calls `lefthalf` and `righthalf` methods at the moment. So for 3,4,5,6,7,8 threads I should write additional methods.
How can i handle this?

two_threaded_merge_sort.java

```
public class two_threaded_merge_sort {

public static void finalMerge(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int i=0; 
    int j=0; 
    int r=0;
    while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
        if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
            result[r]=a[i];
            i++;
            r++;
        } else {
            result[r]=b[j];
            j++;
            r++;
        }
        if (i==a.length) {
            while (j<b.length) {
                result[r]=b[j];
                r++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        if (j==b.length) {
            while (i<a.length) {
                result[r]=a[i];
                r++;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] original = new int[9000000];
    for (int i=0; i<original.length; i++) {
        original[i] = rand.nextInt(1000);
    }

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int[] subArr1 = new int[original.length/2];
    int[] subArr2 = new int[original.length - original.length/2];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, subArr1, 0, original.length/2);
    System.arraycopy(original, original.length/2, subArr2, 0, original.length - original.length/2);

    Worker runner1 = new Worker(subArr1);
    Worker runner2 = new Worker(subArr2);
    runner1.start();
    runner2.start();
    runner1.join();
    runner2.join();
    finalMerge (runner1.getInternal(), runner2.getInternal());
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("2-thread MergeSort takes: " + (float)elapsedTime/1000 + " seconds");
}

}
```

Worker.java

```
class Worker extends Thread {
private int[] internal;

public int[] getInternal() {
    return internal;
}

public void mergeSort(int[] array) {
    if (array.length > 1) {
        int[] left = leftHalf(array);
        int[] right = rightHalf(array);

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);

        merge(array, left, right);
    }
}

public int[] leftHalf(int[] array) {
    int size1 = array.length / 2;
    int[] left = new int[size1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        left[i] = array[i];
    }
    return left;
}

public int[] rightHalf(int[] array) {
    int size1 = array.length / 2;
    int size2 = array.length - size1;
    int[] right = new int[size2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        right[i] = array[i + size1];
    }
    return right;
}

public void merge(int[] result, int[] left, int[] right) {
    int i1 = 0;   
    int i2 = 0;   

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (i2 >= right.length || (i1 < left.length && left[i1] <= right[i2])) {
            result[i] = left[i1];   
            i1++;
        } else {
            result[i] = right[i2];   
            i2++;
        }
    }
}

Worker(int[] arr) {
    internal = arr;
}

public void run() {
    mergeSort(internal);
}
}
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

There needs to be a sort function that separates the array into k parts, then create k threads to sort each part, using either top down or bottom up approach, (bottom up would slightly faster), and wait for all threads to complete.

At this point there are k sorted parts. These could be merged all at once using a k-way merge (complicated), or merged a pair of parts at a time (2 way merge), perhaps using multiple threads, but at this point the process is probably memory bandwidth limited, so multi-threading may not help much.

When separating the array into k parts, something like this can be used to keep the sizes similar:

```
int r = n % k;
int s = n / k;
int t;
for each part{
    t = r ? 1 : 0;
    r -= t;
    size = s + t;
}
```

or

```
int r = n % k;
int s = n / k + 1;
while(r--){
   next part size = s; // n / k + 1
}
s -= 1;
while not done{
   next part size = s; // n / k
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, your hard work is done. now you must parametrize the algorithm with number of threads.

**Your algorithm has two parts**

1. split the work.
2. merge the k-parts.

**And two components:**

1. Main algorithm
2. Workers.

**About the threads**

In my opinion, Start/join method aren't useful in this case, because last merging can't start until all threads are finish. I prefer '2 way merge' (@rcgldr answer) and a thread pool (ExecutorService).
You must be careful with threads synchronization and shared memory.

To sum up, I propose a little different solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class MultithreadedMergeSort {

    private int[] array;
    private int numThreads;
    private List<int[]> sortedFragments;

    private MultithreadedMergeSort(int numThreads, int[] array) {
        this.numThreads = numThreads;
        this.array = array;
    }

    // Basic algorithm: it sort recursively a fragment
    private static void recursiveMergeSort(int[] array, int begin, int end) {
        if (end - begin > 1) {
            int middle = (begin + end) / 2;
            recursiveMergeSort(array, begin, middle);
            recursiveMergeSort(array, middle, end);
            merge(array, begin, middle, end);
        }
    }

    // Basic algorithm: it merges two consecutives sorted fragments
    private static void merge(int[] array, int begin, int middle, int end) {
        int[] firstPart = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, begin, middle);
        int i = 0;
        int j = middle;
        int k = begin;
        while (i < firstPart.length && j < end) {
            if (firstPart[i] <= array[j]) {
                array[k++] = firstPart[i++];
            } else {
                array[k++] = array[j++];
            }
        }
        if (i < firstPart.length) {
            System.arraycopy(firstPart, i, array, k, firstPart.length - i);
        }
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array, int numThreads) throws InterruptedException {
        if (array != null && array.length > 1) {
            if (numThreads > 1) {
                new MultithreadedMergeSort(numThreads, array).mergeSort();
            } else {
                recursiveMergeSort(array, 0, array.length);
            }
        }
    }

    private synchronized void mergeSort() throws InterruptedException {
        // A thread pool
        ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
        this.sortedFragments = new ArrayList<>(numThreads - 1);
        int begin = 0;
        int end = 0;

        // it split the work
        for (int i = 1; i <= (numThreads - 1); i++) {
            begin = end;
            end = (array.length * i) / (numThreads - 1);
            // sending the work to worker
            executors.execute(new MergeSortWorker(begin, end));
        }
        // this is waiting until work is done
        wait();

        // shutdown the thread pool.
        executors.shutdown();
    }

    private synchronized int[] notifyFragmentSorted(int begin, int end) {
        if (begin > 0 || end < array.length) {
            // the array is not completely sorted

            Iterator<int[]> it = sortedFragments.iterator();
            // searching a previous or next fragment
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                int[] f = it.next();
                if (f[1] == begin || f[0] == end) {
                    // It found a previous/next fragment
                    it.remove();
                    return f;
                }
            }
            sortedFragments.add(new int[]{begin, end});
        } else {
            // the array is sorted
            notify();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private class MergeSortWorker implements Runnable {

        int begin;
        int end;

        public MergeSortWorker(int begin, int end) {
            this.begin = begin;
            this.end = end;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Sort a fragment
            recursiveMergeSort(array, begin, end);
            // notify the sorted fragment
            int[] nearFragment = notifyFragmentSorted(begin, end);

            while (nearFragment != null) {
                // there's more work: merge two consecutives sorted fragments, (begin, end) and nearFragment
                int middle;
                if (nearFragment[0] < begin) {
                    middle = begin;
                    begin = nearFragment[0];
                } else {
                    middle = nearFragment[0];
                    end = nearFragment[1];
                }
                merge(array, begin, middle, end);
                nearFragment = notifyFragmentSorted(begin, end);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int numThreads = 5;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] original = new int[9000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
            original[i] = rand.nextInt(1000);
        }

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        MultithreadedMergeSort.sort(original, numThreads);

        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        // warning: Take care with microbenchmarks
        System.out.println(numThreads + "-thread MergeSort takes: " + (float) elapsedTime / 1000 + " seconds");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. But is there any way to divide an array into 4 and 6 and 8 parts equally?

Comment: how can I print the results on the console for the above code? with 20 array elements for example. Thanks

Comment: @Zevs for example: `System.out.print(original[0]); for (int i = 1; i < original.length; i++) {System.out.print(", "+original[i]);}`